# Passport scan compromise

Tags: passports

What can be done with a scanned passport image if given to the wrong people? Should I get a new passport?

I submitted my information to a third party non government company to do my e-visa however, on the official e-visa website it said that particular website was scam.

Comment: Without the country information, do not expect a realistic answer.

Comment: The unofficial website may not necessarily be a scam in terms of fraud, whether eg passport, identity or card related, it may be deemed a ‘scam’ because eg it charges a (higher) fee than the official government website for the same service/product